# Unexpected SIGBUS Exception

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

We are getting the following exception

```
[17:11:44,287][SEVERE][checkpoint-runner-#59][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.StorageException: Failed to write page [file=/home/test/Documents/AdityaISearchTest/gridgain-community-8.7.7/work/db/node00-951ca1c1-fabe-42b9-bbbe-079a9e39141e/cache-GLOBAL/part-455.bin, pageId=283429186830339, tag=1]]]
class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.StorageException: Failed to write page [file=/home/test/Documents/AdityaISearchTest/gridgain-community-8.7.7/work/db/node00-951ca1c1-fabe-42b9-bbbe-079a9e39141e/cache-GLOBAL/part-455.bin, pageId=283429186830339, tag=1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStore.write(FilePageStore.java:607)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStoreManager.writeInternal(FilePageStoreManager.java:535)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$WriteCheckpointPages$1.writePage(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:4516)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl.copyPageForCheckpoint(PageMemoryImpl.java:1296)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl.checkpointWritePage(PageMemoryImpl.java:1211)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$WriteCheckpointPages.writePages(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:4479)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$WriteCheckpointPages.run(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:4405)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No space left on device
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIO.write(AsyncFileIO.java:148)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AbstractFileIO$5.run(AbstractFileIO.java:117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AbstractFileIO.fully(AbstractFileIO.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AbstractFileIO.writeFully(AbstractFileIO.java:115)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStore.write(FilePageStore.java:570)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No space left on device
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7324)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:190)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.getUninterruptibly(GridFutureAdapter.java:145)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIO.write(AsyncFileIO.java:145)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.pwrite0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.pwrite(FileDispatcherImpl.java:66)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:89)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SimpleAsynchronousFileChannelImpl$3.run(SimpleAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:374)
    ... 3 more
```

Client application thrown exception:

```
"" "172.24.112.126" "test" "" "" "" "8688" "com.zoho.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteUtil" "zaddPipeline" "SEVERE" "25-02-2020 00:19:16:457" "40" "" "com.zoho.scrapy.server.ignite.ScrapyIgniteException: IGNITE EXCEPTION :: Exception while sql bulk setting key, value to Ignite db - URLS. Exception -
        at com.zoho.scrapy.server.ignite.IgniteConnectionHandler$CacheHolder.sqlPipelinedSet(IgniteConnectionHandler.java:385)
        at com.zoho.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteUtil.zaddPipeline(IgniteUtil.java:384)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.frontier.WorkQueues.putAll(WorkQueues.java:157)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.frontier.Frontier.scheduleAll(Frontier.java:126)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.processPage(WebCrawler.java:537)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.run(WebCrawler.java:291)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to communicate with Ignite cluster.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:819)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:226)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.executeWithArguments(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:251)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:239)
        at com.zoho.scrapy.server.ignite.IgniteQuery$URLS_OBJECT.sqlBulkInsert(IgniteQuery.java:320)
        at com.zoho.scrapy.server.ignite.IgniteQuery.executeFieldsQuery(IgniteQuery.java:63)
        at com.zoho.scrapy.server.ignite.IgniteConnectionHandler$CacheHolder.sqlPipelinedSet(IgniteConnectionHandler.java:382)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read incoming message (not enough data).
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.read(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:659)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.read(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:637)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.readResponse(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:559)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.sendRequest(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:529)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:798)
```

We would like to know why this issue is occurring.

1) Disk persistence is enabled.
2) This occurred in test setup where client and server would be on same machine.
3) At the time of issue the client node printed this metric

```
 ^-- Node [id=ff1b3829, uptime=03:04:00.904]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=2, CPUs=8]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.03%, avg=5.46%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=0]
    ^-- Heap [used=338MB, free=90.45%, comm=1147MB]
    ^-- Off-heap [used=0MB, free=-1%, comm=0MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]"
```

4) When checked disk pace it's showing still 37% free.
5) The server node metric is as follows (client left).

```
 ^-- Node [id=db7d9a8d, uptime=00:19:00.064]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=1, CPUs=8]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.17%, avg=0.25%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=229594]
    ^-- Heap [used=191MB, free=94.58%, comm=358MB]
    ^-- Off-heap [used=907MB, free=73.96%, comm=3384MB]
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [used=0MB, free=99.99%, comm=100MB]
    ^--   default region [used=907MB, free=71.51%, comm=3184MB]
    ^--   metastoreMemPlc region [used=0MB, free=99.96%, comm=0MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [used=0MB, free=100%, comm=100MB]
    ^-- Ignite persistence [used=951MB]
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [used=0MB]
    ^--   default region [used=951MB]
    ^--   metastoreMemPlc region [used=0MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [used=0MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
```

6) An issue is logged in error file of Ignite. Some of its content pasted here

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f5478007000):  JavaThread "client-connector-#71" [_thread_in_Java, id=15658, stack(0x00007f533fee6000,0x00007f533ffe7000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 7 (SIGBUS), si_code: 2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr: 0x00007f533d4f5000

Registers:
RAX=0x000000076ef45cc8, RBX=0x0000000000001000, RCX=0x00007f533d4f5690, RDX=0xffffffffffffff30
RSP=0x00007f533ffe45e0, RBP=0x00007f533ffe45e0, RSI=0x00007f533d4f4698, RDI=0x000000076ef45cc0
R8 =0x00007f533a432000, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x00007f556d052e20, R11=0x0000000000001000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000030c2698, R14=0x000000076ef37330, R15=0x00007f5478007000
RIP=0x00007f556d052842, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010296, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

7) The config file of server has this IgniteConfiguration

```
<bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
    <property name="queryThreadPoolSize" value="16" />
    <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="300000"/>
    <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="300000"/>

      <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
          <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
          <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
          <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
        </bean>
          </property>
        </bean>
      </property>
</bean>
```

8) df -kh output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   50M  1.6G   4% /run
/dev/dm-0        96G  8.2G   86G   9% /
tmpfs           7.8G   25M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p4  954M  422M  441M  49% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p3  976M  3.5M  972M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/dm-2        97G   17M   96G   1% /personal
/dev/dm-1       284G  181G  104G  64% /home
tmpfs           1.6G   92K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1001
```

9) df -i output

```
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           2030170   562 2029608    1% /dev
tmpfs          2037855   857 2036998    1% /run
/dev/dm-0            0     0       0     - /
tmpfs          2037855    36 2037819    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          2037855     8 2037847    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          2037855    17 2037838    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p4       0     0       0     - /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p3       0     0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/dm-2            0     0       0     - /personal
/dev/dm-1            0     0       0     - /home
tmpfs          2037855    36 2037819    1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Please provide complete Ignite log file.

Comment: As far as I can see there's `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` in the server log. The output of the `df -kh` says that `/home` has enough space. Is it possible that you've run out of `inodes`? Try `$ df -i | grep 'home' | awk '{print $5}'`.

Comment: @VladimirPligin I've edited the post. Please check.

Comment: @alamar In work/ folder there is a log file but nothing is logged in that file.. During the checkpoint process.. But I could see some fatal error print logged in terminal saying -> An error report file with more information is saved as /home/test/Documents/AdityaISearchTest/gridgain-community-8.7.7/hs_err_pid21888.log. Upon checking I could find the content printed in 6th point. Do you want full content of it? I also have binary core dump.

Comment: Yes, please upload them somewhere.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SL3xO8Vj3HrHoKNG9ekix7-VMLdWsA9t/view?usp=sharing -> log file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JHkYubDsHy7uOGTr8aYWBtg6927bt4s/view -> core file

Comment: @alamar Please find the files attached. I hope it helps. But I guess, you still need more info in which case I'd be helpless.

Comment: Have you tried running the same scenario on a different machine (such as cloud VM), see if you can get the same issue? I think it may go away if you change something in the environment. Maybe you do actually run out of disk space on some of the drives for a brief duration.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same. I have a new test machine which I could run. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @RSSAH, by the way I wasn't able to open your core dump, maybe you should attach core.1826 file? Or the dump is broken somehow.

Comment: @alamar I've tried this in a new machine and I couldn't reproduce the issue. Guess it's a machine memory oriented issue.